# How do I allow XP limited user to install fonts?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, fonts, limited-user-account

How do I allow limited user to install fonts? I can't give administrator's rights to the staff at my workplace, but they need to be able to install new fonts to do their graphic design work.

OS: Windows XP Pro SP3

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use a font manager anyway, as having loads of fonts installed in the system will slow it down.  Also, selecting fonts from a massive list is very difficult.

A font manager will allow the user to activate sets of fonts temporarily and also makes it much easier to select the right font.

I use Extensis Suitcase, since my days of being an architect, but there are lots of free ones available as well.

eg. [**AMP Font Viewer**](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php) works fine with XP, but not later.

[image: AMP Font Viewer]

[**Here is an explanation and list of alternative font managers.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_management_software)

Comment: Nice, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @harrymc: Yes it does.  Using a font manager alows the user to activate and use fonts while being a limited user.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_management_software

Answer (score 0):

Give the user "write"+"change" rights to the Fonts folder (`%SystemRoot%\Fonts`).

```
cacls "%SystemRoot%\Fonts" /e /g Joe:C
```

Comment: You got there first. Even if this works, the user might be required to logout and back for this to take effect.

Comment: @harrymc: Filesystem permission changes take effect immediately (unlike user account changes, which require a logout to get the updated token).

Comment: This might not just be just a permission change. If required registry keys are constructed during the logon, then logoff may be necessary for a limited account.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I was referring to the installation of a font requiring a logout, not the filesystem changes.